# Python script... I need to take API Key from the command prompt into Main.py

Tags: python, excel

Need help to take an API key from the command prompt and insert it into a particular cell of an excel sheet. I plan to add it into Main.py. but not sure where in the script.

```
 API_key = input("What is the API key? \n")
```

Then I plan to use Openpyxl to add this into the cell on the excel sheet. But where do I add this code? In the Main.py script? Taken directly from the Openpyxl docs:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = API_key

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: If you're going to enter this at the keyboard anyway, why not just bring up Excel and type it into the cell?  What are you saving here?  The answer is that you need to ask for the input any time before you USE the value.

Comment: The Excel will be a shared document. However, AIP Key is unique for each employee. (just like a password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your description works.
You can do it like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
API_key = input("What is the API key? \n")
sheet['A1'] = API_key
book.save("sample.xlsx")
```